# Error message when I am trying lambda function to be integrated in API Gateway in AWS When I am checking the endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This is my main.py file which has lambda function defined in it.When I am trying to execute this in linux terminal with the following command, I am getting the output.

Command used in linux terminal : sudo serverless invoke local -f aimodel-lambda -d '{"body":[500]}'
output:

```
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "body": 89.01565538975994
   }
```

**main.py file:**

```
import pickle
import boto3
from botocore.vendored import requests
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
import json

def get_model():
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    # s3client = boto3.client("s3")
    # s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    bucket_name ='deploy-simpleml'
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    s3_client.download_file('deploy-simpleml','finalized_model.sav','/tmp/finalized_model.sav')
    model = pickle.load(open("/tmp/finalized_model.sav",'rb'))
    return model
    # # bucket_name = 'deploy-simpleml'
    # # bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name) 
    # bucket= boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name)
    # s3_client.download_file('model/finalized_model.sav','/tmp/finalized_model.sav')
    # model = pickle.load(open("finalized_model.sav",'rb'))
    # return model
 #    # bucket.download_file('model/finalized_model.sav','/tmp/finalized_model.sav')
 #    # model= pickle.load(open("finalized_model.sav",'rb'))
 #    # return model

def predict(event):
    sample =event['body']
    sample=np.array(sample)
    sample = sample.reshape(-1,1)
    # x = x.values.reshape(-1,1)
    model = get_model()
    result = model.predict(sample)
    return result

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    result = predict(event)
    response = {'StatusCode':200,
    'body': result[0]}
    return response
```

I am triggering the code through "serverless.yml " file:

**Serverless.yml File**

```
service : test

plugins:
 - serverless-python-requirements

provider:
 name: aws
 runtime: python3.6
 region : ap-southeast-2
 deploymentBucket:
  name : deploy-simpleml

IamRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName: "test-deploy-dev-ap-southeast-2-lambdaRole"
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: "*"
          Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:

            - s3.*
            - s3.GetObject
            - lambda:InvokeFunction
            - lambda:InvokeAsync
            - execute-api:Invoke
            - execute-api:InvalidateCache


    Resource:
      - "arn:-----------------------------------given my method request ARN number-------"
    # Condition:

    #   StringEquals:

    #     aws:sourceVpce": "9896d9ff"

custom:
 pythonRequirements:
  slim : true
  pythonBin: /usr/bin/python3

environment:
    SLS_DEBUG: serverless-deploy

functions:
  # postApiTest:

  #   handler: main.lambda_handler
  #   name: post-api-test
  #   events:
  #     - http:
  #         path: dev
  #         method: post
  #         private: true
  aimodel-lambda:

    name: aimodel-lambda-function
    description : deploy trained linear reg model on aws lambda using serverless
    handler : main.lambda_handler
    events :

      - http:


          path: GET/testapi

          method: GET
          private: true
```

Then I have created API Gateway, by adding resource, and method as GET and in Integration request, I have selected in the mapping template as "application/json" and in the editor I have given the following command by selecting "empty".

```
{
  "body" : "$input.params("500")"
}
```

and in the method execution , in URL Query String Parameters, I have given body.

[for reference i have added string parameter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qhzG.png)

and when i check the end point url i am facing below error :

```
{"errorMessage": "'body'", "errorType": "KeyError", "stackTrace": [["/var/task/main.py", 38, "lambda_handler", "result = predict(event)"], ["/var/task/main.py", 29, "predict", "sample =event['body']"]]}
```

and when I click on Test and give the parameters in the query strings, [method execution query string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn1ph.png)

I am getting the following error.Please help me with this.

body response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/main.py",
      38,
      "lambda_handler",
      "result = predict(event)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/main.py",
      34,
      "predict",
      "result = model.predict(sample)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py",
      225,
      "predict",
      "return self._decision_function(X)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py",
      207,
      "_decision_function",
      "X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/sklearn/utils/validation.py",
      531,
      "check_array",
      "array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/numpy/core/_asarray.py",
      85,
      "asarray",
      "return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you check what `event` actually is: `print(event)`. Then check cloudwatch logs for the print out.

Comment: ddnot get ur comment,Are you talking about predict(event)???

Comment: @mokugo-devops already answered. Have you checked that? And i'm talking about just regular `print` function in python to print out the `event`.

Comment: with the main.py file, I am able to get the output in linux terminal using the command  I  . I have provided both the command and output in the post...the issue is when I am trying to integrate with API gateway using lambda function in AWS.

Comment: any other solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Numpy reshape on line 34 creates an [array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

You model expects either a string or integer which is why this error is returned.